# display data form multiple tables in a strongly typed view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a strongly typed view which displays students from a database table "Student_A"

View:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Student.Models.Student_A>>" %>
    <table>
    <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(item.StudentName) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(item.StudentId) %>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <% } %>

    </table>
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult ShowStudents()
    {
        ViewData.Model = stud.Student_A.Where(a => a.StudentId != 0);
        return View();
    }
```

I have another table "Student_B" which stores students as well, I would like to display this students in my view as well. Something like:

```
    public ActionResult ShowAllStudents()
    {
        var StudentA = stud.Student_A.Where(a => a.StudentId != 0);
        var StudentB = stud.Student_B.Where(a => a.StudentId != 0);
        ViewData.Model = StudentA + StudentB;

        return View();
    }
```

Is it possible to show data from two different tables in a strongly typed view in a single controller action? Or will I have to create a database view that displays students from "Student_A" and "Student_B" tables and then display them in a view?

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

you need to store the resutls in an "agnostic" way.  For example

```
public class StudentInfo
{
public string Type { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
...
}


var students = stud.Student_A.Where(...).Select(a => new StudentInfo { Type = "Student_A", FirstName = a.FirstName, LastName = a.LastName });

students.concat( stud.Student_B.Where(...).Select(b => new StudentInfo { Type = "Student_B", FirstName = b.FirstName, LastName = b.LastName });

ViewData.Model = students;

return View();
```

By doing this, you have a common class of student info to store common properties which can be used as a strongly-typed model.

Alternatively, if you want to list them SEPARATELY, you could create a composite ViewModel

```
public class StudentsVM
{
public IEnumerable<Student_A> Student_A { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<Student_B> Student_B { get; set; }
}

var vm = new StudentsVM;
vm.Student_A = stud.Student_A.Where(...);
vm.Student_B = stud.STudent_B.Where(...);

ViewData.Model = vm;
```

Comment: What will my view inherit? "Object"?

Comment: With your first approach, how do I display the results in view?

Comment: Your model is `IEnumerable<StudentInfo>`

Comment: this list contains multiple students, wont I have too loop through model items to display all? It gives and error if i don't have "IEnumerable<StudentsViewModel>". However when I add "IEnumerable" I get the following error: Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'StudentsViewModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What namespace is `StudentsViewModel` in?  `IEnumerable<Full.Namespace.Of.StudentsViewMode>`  Alternatively, you can add the namespace in the web.config.  See your web.config for a list of current automatically imported namespaces.  But for test, I'd start by using the full namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view model with both

```
public class StudentsViewModel
{
  public List<Student.Models.Student_A> StudentsA {get;set}
  public List<Student.Models.Student_B> StudentsA {get;set}
}
```

and return this in your view, if indeed the A and B students have different fields

```
var viewModel = new StudentsViewModel();
viewModel.StudentsA = stud.Student_A.Where(a => a.StudentId != 0);
viewModel.StudentsB = stud.Student_B.Where(a => a.StudentId != 0);
return View(viewModel);
```

Comment: Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<StudentsViewModel>

Comment: this list contains multiple students, hence ill have to loop through the model items. It gives and error if i dont have "IEnumerable<StudentsViewModel>". However when I add "IEnumerable" I get the following error: Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'StudentsViewModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar for a Treeview instead of a table and needed to combine two different collections in order to generate a treeview from a single collection. In my case I was able to combine them using this...

```
var allStudents = StudentA.Union((IEnumerable<Object>)StudentB);
```

Then in your code when you iterate through each object in the collection you can test the datatype of the object and display it how you want, in case you want to use different code to render different types of students. I needed to do this because in my case a node that had child items was a completely different type than the node without child items.

Note that by using Object as your root collection type instead of some sort of shared inheritance (an interface for example) you'll have no way to sort your combined collection or filter them.

If you need to mix the two collections rather than just appending one to the end of the other, you'll have to use some sort of shared inheritance.

**UPDATE**:

Sample code to show that this works. I tested in [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), but I'm sure it'd work just as well in Visual Studio.

```
public class Student_A
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
}

public class Student_B
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    public string MiddleName{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
}

void Main()
{
    List<Student_A> StudentAs = new List<Student_A>();
    StudentAs.Add(new Student_A(){Id = 1, FirstName = "Jack", LastName = "Smith"});
    StudentAs.Add(new Student_A(){Id = 3, FirstName = "Sarah", LastName = "Jane"});
    StudentAs.Add(new Student_A(){Id = 7, FirstName = "Zack", LastName = "Hall"});

    List<Student_B> StudentBs = new List<Student_B>();
    StudentBs.Add(new Student_B(){Id = 2, FirstName = "Jane", MiddleName = "T.", LastName = "Kelly"});
    StudentBs.Add(new Student_B(){Id = 9, FirstName = "Rose", MiddleName = "Marie", LastName = "Tyler"});
    StudentBs.Add(new Student_B(){Id = 4, FirstName = "Bobby", MiddleName = "Stephen", LastName = "Singer"});

    var result = StudentAs.Union((IEnumerable<Object>)StudentBs);

    result.Dump();
}
```

Comment: Cant have a strongly typed view this way, correct? What would my view inherit in this case?

Comment: For the actual line defining the page's view model at the top, you're right `@model IEnumerable<object>`. But when you iterate through the collection of objects you can cast or address the objects as their actual types if you want in order to get the correct intellisense. Alternatively you can pass a strongly typed view model with the collections as separate properties and combine them in the view for your needs to show them in a single table. Which if I recall is what I ended up doing in my case as well.

Comment: Get an error when I tried your suggested way: 'System.collections.Generic.List<Student.Models.Student_A> does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Union<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: It's an extension method in System.Linq, you may have to make sure that namespace resolves from the page you're using it.

Comment: I just checked and it seems to work fine for me, the only difference in my exact line of code is some sorting... Here's the line from my project, maybe it will help you figure out why yours seems to give that error?
`(typeItem.Structures.OrderBy(x => x.Priority).ThenBy(x => x.DisplayName)).Union((IEnumerable<Object>)typeItem.Types.OrderBy(x => x.DisplayName))`
Maybe cast the first collection to IEnumerable<object> as well?

Comment: I get a this error when I do it this way:
        var StudentA = stud.Student_A.Where(a => a.StudentId != 0);
        var StudentB = stud.Student_B.Where(a => a.StudentId != 0);
var AllStudents = (IEnumerable<Object>)StudentA.Union((IEnumerable<Object>)StudentB);
                ViewData.Model = AllStudents;
                return View();

Error: The type arguments for rmethod 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Union<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Check out the sample code I just uploaded showing a working example. You may have to add some calls to .ToList() to force evaluation of your Line methods before the union tries to combine them.

Comment: Get the same error as I got earlier:
'System.collections.Generic.List<Student.Models.Student_A> does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Union<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you. I'm running an MVC project with that logic on a live server running .NET 4.0. I honestly don't know why it won't work for you when it works for me, it even worked in a standalone environment in LinqPad, so all I can assume is it's something to do with your setup.